# Proof about congruences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

My Professor defines a congruence relation $R$ over a group $G$ as
$aRb\wedge cRd\Rightarrow acRbd$, for each $a,b,c,d\in G$.

I'm trying to prove the following:
 Let $G$ be a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and consider the equivalence relations $R_d^H$ and $R_e^H$ defined as

$xR_d^Hy\Leftrightarrow xy^{-1}\in H$ and $xR_e^Hy\Leftrightarrow x^{-1}y\in H$.

Then the following statements are equivalent:

1) $R_d^H$ is a congruence relation;

2) $R_d^H=R_e^H$;

3) $R_e^H$ is a congruence relation.

Any tips on how to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is not a congruence relation that you defines, but the compatibility of a relation with the group law.

Comment: I'm translating it from portuguese, so it might be called something else. I also found a book that calls it a congruence $\mathrm{mod }H$.

Comment: Isn't $R$  an equivalence relation?

Comment: Yes. Can't a congruence be an equivalent relation?

Comment: It seems that what your teacher calls a congruence on a group is an equivalence relation compatible with the group law.

Comment: Wikipedia gives me the same definition of a congruence over a group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation)

Comment: This is what I said in my previous comment.